# Add a row in Dojo datagrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

Struggling to find a bit of code to easily understand.

How do you add a row and clear all rows in a Dojo datagrid (version 1.4.2).  Lets say the data is 2 columns with customerID and address.

I am using

```
dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore
```

to store values in - but again not quite sure how this should be used.

It can't be that hard.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the data store reference from the grid using `grid.store`, then you can use `store.newItem()` to create a new item in the store. This new item is added as a new row in the grid. For example, `store.newItem({customerID : 1, address : "Somewhere"})`.

To clear all the rows, you can either loop all the items in the data store and use `deleteItem()` to remove all the items, or use the internal function `_clearData()` in data grid to remove all the rows, or use `setStore()` to set a new empty store to the grid. I prefer to use a empty store to reset the grid.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are correct, but you also need to call `save()` on the write store to "commit" the change. When you save, a widget using the store (datagrid for example) will refresh itself.

Also, `newItem()` returns the new item you just created so if you don't want to pass an object to `newItem` just modify its return value, then `save()` the store.

Pseudo code:

```
var i = store.newItem({});

store.setValue(i,"newattribute1","new value");
store.setValue(i,"newattribute2","new value 2");

store.save();
```

[Here is the relevant docs for ItemFileWriteStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/api/Write.html) which tell how to use `newItem()`, `setValue()`, and `save()`.

Instead of deleteItem, you should use `setStore(new ItemFileWriteStore())`, but I suspect there is a memory leak when you do this, be careful. This makes a new blank store to be used with the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I have finish one example about this... the code is here

```
//First we create the buttons to add/del rows
var addBtn = new dijit.form.Button({
        id: "addBtn",
        type: "submit",
        label: "Add Row"
    },
    "divAddBtn");//div where the button will load
```

var delBtn = new dijit.form.Button({
        id: "delBtn",
        type: "submit",
        label: "Delete Selected Rows"
    },
    "divDelBtn");

//Connect to onClick event of this buttons the respective actions to add/remove rows.
//where grid is the name of the grid var to handle.
dojo.connect(addBtn, "onClick", function(event) {
        // set the properties for the new item:
        var myNewItem = {
            id: grid.rowCount+1,
            type: "country",
            name: "Fill this country name"
        };
        // Insert the new item into the store:
        // (we use store3 from the example above in this example)
        store.newItem(myNewItem);
    });

`dojo.connect(delBtn, "onClick", function(event) {
    // Get all selected items from the Grid:
    var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
        if (items.length) {
        // Iterate through the list of selected items.
        // The current item is available in the variable
        // "selectedItem" within the following function:
            dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem) {
                if (selectedItem !== null) {
                    // Delete the item from the data store:
                    store.deleteItem(selectedItem);
                } // end if
            }); // end forEach
        } // end if
});`