# How to insert row in dojox DataGrid

Tags: dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojo

Is there any way to insert a row between the existing rows in dojox DataGrid ? At present I am deleting all the items and then re-inserting them. This is got to be a better way than this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a row in Dojo datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546719/add-a-row-in-dojo-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use addRow() function of grid to insert a new row with empty values in it else if you want to add row with values in it then update the grid store and refresh the grid.

Comment: addRow appends the row in the end I want the row inserted in between.